# Inverting case in Scala

Tags: scala, stringbuilder

```
for (i <- marker to cursor - 1 ){        
    if (buffer.charAt(i).isUpper){
        buffer.charAt(i).toString.toLowerCase
    } else if (buffer.charAt(i).isLower) {
        buffer.charAt(i).toString.toUpperCase
    }      
}
```

I've tried multiple methods to achieve but can't figure a solution and this is where I'm at. While trying other methods I used `slice` but couldn't get it to return a `Bool` for an `if` statement (Converted to a string but isUpper doesn't work on strings). Currently this does nothing to the strings, for context marker/cursor just highlight a selection on a sentence to invert.

Comment: something like `.map({ c => if(c.isUpper) { c.toLower } else { c.toUpper } })` would work?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner:

```
val s = "mixedUpperLower"
s.toUpperCase.zip (s).map {case (a, b) => if (a == b) a.toLower else a}.mkString ("")
res3: String = MIXEDuPPERlOWER
```

Maybe a short method is better readable:

```
scala> def invertCase (c: Char) : Char = if (c.isLower) c.toUpper else c.toLower 
invertCase: (c: Char)Char

scala> s.map (invertCase) 
res4: String = MIXEDuPPERlOWER
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"aBcDef".map(x => if(x.isLower) x.toUpper else x.toLower)
```

prints

> AbCdEF